# Vuetify checkboxes are HUGE

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

With both v-select multiple and combobox, my chexboxes are showing up as huge but are otherwise functioning... how can I fix this? I'm running vuetify@1.5.18, vue-cli  3.4.1 , and vue 2.5.16

I have tried moving the v-select multiple and combobox outside of all my own classes to confirm that it's not the fault of my own formatting, I've also applied  and the link with no effect

[image]

Inspection of  checkbox element shows font-size:24px has been overriden, I need to reverse that override somehow.

[image]

I inspected the checkbox element in my program vs. the Vuetify documentation element, and here is the discrepancy:

[image]

In the above picture from Vuetify documentation, the .v-list-item_action min-width is 24px, but in my program the min-width is 56px:

[image]

How can I adjust the min-width manually?

```
<v-select
   v-model="metadata[index].savedValue"
   :items="metadata[index].options"
   color="orange"
   multiple
   outline
></v-select>
```

Comment: You should inspect the relevant elements to see why the checkboxes are so large and compare that to the elements in a working example from the documentation. If you are unable to establish what the underlying cause of the problem is then you should add the results of that investigation to the question. Otherwise we don't have a lot to go on.

Comment: @skirtle Thank you for the tip! I did just that and added it into the post above, if you have any insight based on this I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: I don't think you've dug down to the correct element. You should look for the `<i>` element with the class `v-icon`. Chances are the problem is that the wrong `font-size` is being set.

Comment: Got down to the <i> element and found that indeed font-size has been overriden, I just don't know how to reverse that or find out where it's being overriden

Comment: @skirtle nvm I found where it was being overridden, it was in a .v-icon {} css snippet in another component!! Thank you!!